# how do I make a song sound like its another song

Tags: sound, editing

A while back I saw a song edit on twitter I sparked an interest with and I wanna see if I can do it myself. Anyway how and what program I can achieve this with?

https://twitter.com/Waltmann13/status/1142253763870068736

Answer (score -3):

Any daw where u can edit samples (be able to chop cut and paste) then just move that section (drag and drop)most if not any current daw will can auto sync to the music backing track.hope this helps with ur ?

Comment: Can you add any more detail.  I think I get what you are trying to say, but it currently is kind of hard to understand what you are suggesting if someone isn't already familiar with DAWs and remixing.